# i am unable to get past the welcome screen to install

Tags: system-installation

I am booting to install using from usb and i get stuck on the welcome screen, my mouse or keyboard will not work to continue install. help.

Answer (score 0):

This never happened but you can tried the following solutions

- Try **unplugging your keyboard** and/or mouse in other USB port
- **Enable** `USB Device Legacy Suppor` in your BIOS settings
- Maybe try plug your Keyboard and/or Mouse **in USB 2.0** and not 3.0 if you were on 2.0 ports

If there is only your keyboard that works you can use:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> : to change selection
- <kbd>Space</kbd> : to valid
  a checkbox
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> : to press a button

Comment: I forgot to mention that its actually on my laptop. sorry.

Comment: OK I understand.  I think it would be better to edit your question by specifying the model of your computer so that we can help you better. Otherwise, perhaps by connecting an external keyboard, you will be able to finalize the installation. And maybe updating the kernel will solve your problem.  I know it's a little dirty as a solution.

Comment: ahh sorry understood, its a mid 2017 Apple 13.3" MacBook Pro with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 Dual-Core.